# How to hit the url in WordPress rest_api_init

Tags: wordpress, rest, api

I have set up the API end points in WordPress in theme `functions.php`.

```
    add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'myplugin/v1', '/author/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'my_awesome_func',
        'args' => array(
            'id' => array(
                'validate_callback' => function($param, $request, $key) {
                    return is_numeric( $param );
                }
            ),
        ),
    ));
});
```

And the callback function is like:

```
function my_awesome_func( $data ) {
    $posts = get_posts( array(
        'author' => $data['id'],
    ) );
    if ( empty( $posts ) ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'awesome_no_author', 'Invalid author', array( 'status' => 404 ) );
    }
    return $posts[0]->post_title;
}
```

I want to know what will be the url for this API and how can I hit that url?
Please help me out. I know this is simple thing but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: I think I found the solution 
My wordpress version was <4.4. After updating the wordpress, everything is working fine. 
So the Url will be like http://example.com/wp-json/myplugin/v1/author/1 Remember to add /wp-json/ part in url

Comment: can you post url update code?

Comment: Its same as I asked the question.

Comment: You said end point should be http://example.com/wp-json/myplugin/v1/author/1

Comment: Please read my comment. Its mentioned in there.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get from your question and comments. Please elaborate?

Comment: What you didnt get? Its simple
`example.com/wp-json/myplugin/v1/author/1`
if you want to hit url and want to get the data then you will hit the url like above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147300/discussion-between-susheel-and-vel).